# Display only specific parts of an array that has been retrieved from a JSON file

Tags: php, json, api

I have been trying for hours since last night to display a newsfeed from the battle.net APIs to my WoW guild's website.
I have managed to get the JSON file from battle.net, but can't work out how to display the newsfeed. I will enclose my code and the json file I am working with.

PHP

```
<section class='cont'>
    <div class='intro'>
        <p>Intorduction to the page</p>
    </div>
    <div class='feed'>
        <p>A Newsfeed</p>
       <?php
        $json = file_get_contents("https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/guild/Vek'Nilash/Renascence?fields=news&locale=en_GB&apikey=f43uf742srjkmvpnk76u52pw5nz5kga5");
        $feed = json_decode($json);
        $feedcount = 1;
            foreach($feed as $newsfeed)
                while ($feedcount <= 12) {
                    echo $feed->news['type'];
                    ++$feedcount;
                }
            echo '<div>' . print_r($feed, true) . '</div>';
        ?>
    </div>
```

JSON (part only as it is over 2000 lines long)

```
{
"lastModified": 1484495787000,
"name": "Renascence",
"realm": "Vek'nilash",
"battlegroup": "Glutsturm / Emberstorm",
"level": 25,
"side": 1,
"achievementPoints": 2565,
"emblem": {
    "icon": 60,
    "iconColor": "ffb1b8b1",
    "iconColorId": 14,
    "border": 3,
    "borderColor": "ffffffff",
    "borderColorId": 14,
    "backgroundColor": "ff4f2300",
    "backgroundColorId": 44
},
"news": [{
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Garnatou",
    "timestamp": 1484495940000,
    "itemId": 137514,
    "context": "challenge-mode",
    "bonusLists": [3415, 1507, 1813]
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Belladona",
    "timestamp": 1484495820000,
    "itemId": 134203,
    "context": "world-quest-8",
    "bonusLists": [3473, 603, 1507, 3336]
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Fireplume",
    "timestamp": 1484495760000,
    "itemId": 134204,
    "context": "world-quest-9",
    "bonusLists": [3474, 42, 604, 1507, 1674]
}, {
    "type": "playerAchievement",
    "character": "Tsula",
    "timestamp": 1484495700000,
    "context": "",
    "bonusLists": [],
    "achievement": {
        "id": 6193,
        "title": "Level 90",
        "points": 10,
        "description": "Reach level 90.",
        "rewardItems": [],
        "icon": "achievement_level_90",
        "criteria": [{
            "id": 5212,
            "description": "Reach level 90",
            "orderIndex": 1,
            "max": 90
        }],
        "accountWide": false,
        "factionId": 2
    }
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Rockz",
    "timestamp": 1484495700000,
    "itemId": 143684,
    "context": "world-quest-8",
    "bonusLists": [3473, 1507, 3336]
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Rukor",
    "timestamp": 1484495700000,
    "itemId": 113987,
    "context": "raid-mythic",
    "bonusLists": [567]
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Trolljäger",
    "timestamp": 1484495520000,
    "itemId": 143684,
    "context": "world-quest-9",
    "bonusLists": [3474, 1507, 1674]
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Rockz",
    "timestamp": 1484495400000,
    "itemId": 129067,
    "context": "",
    "bonusLists": [1794, 1735]
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Angël",
    "timestamp": 1484495340000,
    "itemId": 137531,
    "context": "dungeon-mythic",
    "bonusLists": [1727, 1808, 1492, 1813]
}, {
    "type": "itemLoot",
    "character": "Rockz",
    "timestamp": 1484495340000,
    "itemId": 134316,
    "context": "world-quest-9",
    "bonusLists": [3474, 1507, 1674]
}
```

]
}

I only want the first 12 items from the array ['news'].

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can tell from the `print_r()` the newsfeed is in an object called `news` and this is an array of objects. So loop over those objects.

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/guild/Vek'Nilash/Renascence?fields=news&locale=en_GB&apikey=f43uf742srjkmvpnk76u52pw5nz5kga5");
$feed = json_decode($json);
$feedcount = 0;
foreach($feed->news as $newsfeed) {
    if ($feedcount >= 12 ) {
        break;
    }
    echo $newsfeed->type . PHP_EOL;
    ++$feedcount;
}
```

Comment: Awsome. I can back to work on it now I have the concept. Thank you. great answer.